# Tomcat Crashing after SSH Disconnection

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, x11-forwarding

I am using **apache-tomcat-8.5.15** ; with java version being 1.8. The tomcat contains a war that has the following function:

```
public static boolean GenFVUFile(String txtFilePath, String errFilePath, String outputFilepath) {
        try {
            
            String[] inputParameters = {txtFilePath + fileName + ".txt", errFilePath + fileName + ".err", outputFilepath + fileName + ".fvu", "0", "1.73"};
            PAOFvu pao = new PAOFvu();
            System.out.println("inputParameters1:: "+inputParameters);
            pao.main(inputParameters);
                   
            
            File errFile = new File(errFilePath + fileName + ".err");
            boolean exists = errFile.exists();
            System.out.println("Old file Name :: " + fileName);
            if (exists) {
                boolean status = GenErrFile(txtFilePath, errFilePath);
                GenTextFile(accDay,acctMonth, acctYear);

                System.out.println("New file Name :: " + fileName);
               GenFVUFile(txtFilePath, errFilePath, outputFilepath);
               
            }
```

The tomcat is deployed in a Linux Server. The code line:
PAOFvu pao = new PAOFvu() has java.awt component and requires X11 display variable; hence unsetting display variable will not result in successful execution of the code. Also for the tomcat is being run on -Djava.awt.headless=true  mode.
The issue is: the code only works if the server having the tomcat being connected through SSH remote connection. The tomcat crashes upon disconnection of SSH remote.

Comment: You will need to append & to the end of the command to execute tomcat in order for it to run in the background

Comment: Exactly which command are you referring to. The only command I am executing is running startup.sh command to start the tomcat.

Comment: So run "startup.sh &" in order to run the script in the background

Comment: The result of **startup.sh** and **startup.sh &** (no hup) are same. The script just starts the tomcat.

Comment: Using `startup.sh &` should be unnecessary because `startup.sh` simply calls `catalina.sh start` - and the `catalina.sh` script should take care of adding `&` to the Java command it uses to run Tomcat. Also, the `&` (running in the background) is not the same as using `nohup` (avoid termination of background processes when exiting the parent process).

Comment: Take a look at the `catalina.sh` script - and look at the documentation for the `USE_NOHUP` environment variable. See if setting that environment variable helps in your situation.

Comment: The issue is resolved. I had to export DISPLAY=0.0, this by passed the X11 variable requirements. Changing the Tomcat port to -1 so that it doesn't crash.

Comment: Great! Glad you solved it. You are welcome to post that comment as an answer, to provide full details - and to make it easier for other people to find your solution. You can even accept your own answer, if you want.